# How to create a view where all data are collected concerning the person who uses the view in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, identifier

The data should come from table `Emp` and from the other tables `Dept` and `Salgrade`. Assume that the user's identifier is available through the constant user (see the result of the query: `SELECT User FROM Dual;`) is the same as the value `Ename`. I want to create a row in table `Emp` with own identifier as `Ename`.

DB:

EMP

```
EMPNO | ENAME  |   JOB   |    MGR | HIREDATE |  SAL | COMM |DEPTNO 
----- ------- --------- ---- --------- ----- ---- ------ 
 7839 KING    PRESIDENT NULL 17-NOV-81  5000 NULL     10 
 7698 BLAKE   MANAGER   7839 01-MAY-81  2850 NULL     30 
 7782 CLARK   MANAGER   7839 09-JUN-81  2450 NULL     10 
 7566 JONES   MANAGER   7839 02-APR-81  2975 NULL     20 
 7654 MARTIN  SALESMAN  7698 28-SEP-81  1250 1400     30 
 7499 ALLEN   SALESMAN  7698 20-FEB-81  1600  300     30 
 7844 TURNER  SALESMAN  7698 08-SEP-81  1500    0     30 
 7900 JAMES   CLERK     7698 03-DEC-81   950 NULL     30 
 7521 WARD    SALESMAN  7698 22-FEB-81  1250  500     30 
 7902 FORD    ANALYST   7566 03-DEC-81  3000 NULL     20 
 7369 SMITH   CLERK     7902 17-DEC-80   800 NULL     20 
 7788 SCOTT   ANALYST   7566 09-DEC-82  3000 NULL     20 
 7876 ADAMS   CLERK     7788 12-JAN-83  1100 NULL     20 
 7934 MILLER  CLERK     7782 23-JAN-82  1300 NULL     10
```

DEPT

```
DEPTNO | DNAME    |   LOC 
------ ----------- -------- 
    10 ACCOUNTING  NEW YORK 
    20 RESEARCH    DALLAS 
    30 SALES       CHICAGO 
    40 OPERATIONS  BOSTON
```

SALGRADE

```
GRADE | LOSAL | HISAL 
----- ----- ----- 
    1   700  1200 
    2  1201  1400 
    3  1401  2000 
    4  2001  3000 
    5  3001  9999
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What was the error?  What didn't work the way you expected?  It sounds like you'd just want a `where` clause `where ename = user` assuming you had the appropriate data in the tables.  It's hard to know if you're really asking for the syntax to create a view or if you've run into a problem somewhere or if you have some other sort of issue.

Comment: The main problem in here for me is to find the approach to complete this scenerio. I am a newbie in Oracle (or databases at all). I see the concept of Users and so on but i have no clue on how to apply the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those tables are owned by user `SCOTT` so - connect as it; Scott will create a view and grant other users `select` privileges on a public synonym.

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> create or replace view v_emp as
  2    select d.deptno, d.dname, e.empno, e.ename, e.job
  3    from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  4    where e.ename = user;

View created.

SQL> create public synonym psyn_v_emp for v_emp;

Synonym created.

SQL> grant select on psyn_v_emp to public;

Grant succeeded.
```

OK; so, what does the owner see?

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> select * from psyn_v_emp;

    DEPTNO DNAME               EMPNO ENAME      JOB
---------- -------------- ---------- ---------- ---------
        20 RESEARCH             7788 SCOTT      ANALYST
                                     -----
                                     Scott sees only Scott's data
```

Connect as some other user (I previously created user named `KING`):

```
SQL> connect king/king
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "KING"
SQL> select * from psyn_v_emp;

    DEPTNO DNAME               EMPNO ENAME      JOB
---------- -------------- ---------- ---------- ---------
        10 ACCOUNTING           7839 KING       PRESIDENT
                                     -----
                                     King sees only King's data

SQL>
```

---

Therefore, if I understood what you're asking, that would be "it".

Comment: Yes, perfect! That seems like a solution I needed.

Comment: I'm glad if it helped.